# localhost-magento-store.com/index.php/install Showing Not Found in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: magento, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to install magento on my ubuntu 12.04 ,

I followed follwing tutorial for Download & Setup it on my machine,

http://davidtsadler.com/archives/2012/06/03/how-to-install-magento-on-ubuntu/

Upto  quering www.localhost.magento-store.com it works fine & shows Respective output ..

But while installing magento it fails & shows enter code here

**Not Found
The requested URL  index.php install was not found on this server
Apache 2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost.magento-store.com Port 80**

Comment: can you please post this Question in the blog that you follow? such question is not possible to answer we have to read whole what is written in that blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can write you general installation of Magneto here:

1. Install Apache, php and Mysql in your ubuntu server(addition, install mcrypt)
2. create a folder "magento" in /var/www and give proper write access
3. download magento from magento site and extract it in folder : /var/www/magento so that this folder content index.php
4. go to localhost/magento in browser (you should have mysqlsql database, so you can install phpmyadmin or use command line to create database)
5. Follow the installation step
6. if you want to have specific domain look on Virtualhost of Apache.